# error al llamar evento javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tengo una funcion javascript sacada de: https://gist.github.com/jrobinsonc/5718959

es esta:

```
function number_format(amount, decimals) {

    amount += ''; // por si pasan un numero en vez de un string
    amount = parseFloat(amount.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')); // elimino cualquier cosa que no sea numero o punto

    decimals = decimals || 0; // por si la variable no fue fue pasada

    // si no es un numero o es igual a cero retorno el mismo cero
    if (isNaN(amount) || amount === 0) 
        return parseFloat(0).toFixed(decimals);

    // si es mayor o menor que cero retorno el valor formateado como numero
    amount = '' + amount.toFixed(decimals);

    var amount_parts = amount.split('.'),
        regexp = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while (regexp.test(amount_parts[0]))
        amount_parts[0] = amount_parts[0].replace(regexp, '$1' + ',' + '$2');

    return amount_parts.join('.');
}
```

el problema es que soy un poco novato en javascript y no logro llamar a la función satisfactoriamente.

mi código html es asi:

```
<input type="number" step="any" id="subtotal" value=""
class="form-control input-lg" onkeyup="number_format(amount, decimals);"
placeholder="Escriba el monto" />
```

he intentado de otras maneras también y no he podido...

¿como se escribe el código correctamente para poder usar la función?

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: no da ningún error, pero no ejecuta la función

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guiarte por esto, llamas a `format_subtotal` para modificar el valor del subtotal haciendo uso de la funcion `number_format`, tambien debes cambiar el type del input a text

```
<input type="text" id="subtotal" value=""
class="form-control input-lg" onkeyup="format_subtotal();"
placeholder="Escriba el monto" />

<script>
function format_subtotal() {
  var x = document.getElementById("subtotal");
  x.value = number_format(x.value, 2);
}
</script>
```